# what is the Difference between Cross Browser/site/Domain scripting?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Today i got confused when i was asked What is Cross browser scripting. Here as per my understanding Cross browser Scripting is related to Browser compatibility, Cross Site Scripting is related to java-script hacks & Cross Domain Scripting is related to Ajax calls.

I tried to google it also but not getting clear concept of cross browser scripting.

Please help me to understand the difference.

Comment: Cross browser scripter is hacks that can be specified that will only work in IE7 and some in IE8 ect.

Answer (score 3):

If a script is **cross browser**, it works comparably in all browsers. JavaScript engine in different browsers tend to vary in some minor details.

**Cross domain scripting** is either an attack that tries to hijack user sessions (malicious) or it's a way to communicate with another domain. Cross Domain Scripting aka Cross Origin Resource Sharing is quite tricky to set up.

Answer (score 3):

["Cross-browser Scripting"](http://www.webreference.com/js/article2/index.html) is a somewhat archaic term (you'll see the article linked is dated 1997) meaning writing scripts that work across browsers. More recently this is usually called "browser compatibility".

["Cross-site Scripting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is a type of attack that involves making malicious scripts a part of someone elses page in order to deliver some payload that compromises their visitors.

"Cross-domain Scripting" is generally synonymous with "Cross-site Scripting".

If you have a cross-site scripting attack that works across all browsers, you might be inclined to call it a "Cross Browser Cross Site Scripting" attack, or XBXSS.